# como imprimir uma lista de números com uma soma intercalada?

Tags: java

Eu tenho essa lista de `1` a `10`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Código:

```
List <Long> lista = new ArrayList();

for (long a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
 lista.add(a);
 System.out.print(lista);
}
```

Precisaria de uma soma intercalada nessa lista, com uma variável.

Por exemplo:

```
List <Long> lista = new ArrayList();

    long x,z=200;

for (long a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {

  x=z+a;
  lista.add(x);

        }
 System.out.print(lista);
    }
}
```

Em vez de imprimir a lista normal + `200`:

```
[201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210]
```

Eu queria que a soma fosse intercalada um sim outro não..

```
[1, 202, 3, 204, 5, 206, 7, 208, 9, 210]
```

E eu queria também poder mudar essa distância de quantos pulos para dar a soma na lista poderia ser de `2` em `2` ou `5` em `5`... de `30` em `30`... entende.. dependendo do tamanho da lista... lista de `1` pra `100` de `1` pra `10000`...

Funcionando no Repl: https://repl.it/repls/ShorttermUnfortunatePasswords

Comment: Mas quer somar uma lista e um numero incremental ? duas listas ? dois numeros incrementais ? Você fala de uma lista `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`  mas depois não a usa na soma. Para alem disso não andar de `1` em `1` nessa lista passa os limites, e a menos que seja "circular" não irá funcionar. Todos esses pormenores não ficaram claros na pergunta.

Comment: Boa noite @Isac, eu somei a lista com o número 200, sim preciso que apenas um número incremental some com nessa lista de pulo em pulo pode ser de 2 em 2... 5 em 5... 3 em 3... eu poderia alterar essa distância que ele percorre a soma..

Comment: Continuam coisas por esclarecer para poder ter uma resposta satisfatória. Como iria funcionar pular de 3 em 3 nessa lista que tem apenas 10 elementos ? Exemplifique para que fique claro

Comment: lista de 1 a 10.... pulando elementos de 3 em 3... 
e somando com o número 500... 
[1, 2, 503, 4, 5, 506, 7, 8, 509, 10]

Comment: E de onde vem esse `500` isso seria um numero que incrementa ou esses vem de outra lista ?

Comment: esse número incrementa, ele pode vim de uma variável apenas....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se já tem a lista construída, e quer aplicar uma soma, pulando de `x` em `x` elementos, basta um `for` com um incremento de `x` em `x` que pare quando atingir a quantidade de elementos da lista:

```
int avanco = 3;
int numSoma = 500;
for (int i = avanco - 1; i < lista.size(); i += avanco) {
    lista.set(i, lista.get(i) + numSoma);
}

System.out.println(lista);
```

Para uma lista `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` o código acima produz o seguinte resultado:

```
[1, 2, 503, 4, 5, 506, 7, 8, 509, 10]
```

[Confirme no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wGObOm)

Replare que alterei o valor de cada elemento da lista com o método `set` e fui buscar o valor anterior com `get`. O inicio do `for` teve de ser com `avanco - 1` pois os arrays começam em `0`.

No entanto, uma melhor solução seria gerar logo a lista com os elementos que pretende, evitando assim processamento desnecessário:

```
int avanco = 3;
int numSoma = 500;
List <Long> lista = new ArrayList<>();
for (long a = 1; a <= 10; ++a){
    lista.add(a % avanco == 0 ? a + numSoma: a);
}

System.out.println(lista); //[1, 2, 503, 4, 5, 506, 7, 8, 509, 10]
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/pNlpAu)

Agora adiciona apenas o `a` em casos normais, e quando o numero corrente é múltiplo do `avanco` adiciona a soma dos dois. Assim a lista é toda gerada de uma vez logo com as somas que pretende.

Comment: Esplêndido! Excepcional! Primoroso! Sensacional! Versátil e sutilmente otimizado =D

Comment: meu caro, como funcionaria o mesmo programa para números em "BigInteger" pois não consigo fazer funcionar esse método usando BigInteger...

Comment: @Felipe `BigInteger` é diferente em vários sentidos, pois força a que as operações matematicas sejam feitas com os métodos do próprio objeto. Em vez de somar com `+` teria que somar utilizar o método `add`. No entanto já foge um pouco à questão original (talvez fosse melhor abrir uma nova pergunta com essa nova dúvida). De qualquer forma, aconselho sempre a olhar para a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) para que esteja consciente dos métodos que existem para o `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Essa resposta atende ao seu problema.

```
List <Long> lista = new ArrayList();
long x=200;
long pulo = 3;
for (long a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
 if((a % pulo) == 0){
  lista.add(x+a);
 }else{
   lista.add(a);
 }
}
System.out.print(lista);
```

Comment: Gênial, muito obrigado mano!!!